# PT1000 2 wire probe. Can I add third wire?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, temperature, current-source, rtd

I'v got 2 wire (81 cm) PT1000 probe which I want to utilize in a project.
I would like to use current source and couple of opamps to make the measurement through ADC (uC) just like described here: [link1](http://www.splok.org/PT1000_Interface).
The point is I need to reach measurement spot which is 5 meters away. I will  measure added wire resitance by multimeter and substract it in uC.

As I understand from [link1](http://www.splok.org/PT1000_Interface) PT1000 3 wire probe has been used there (first image on the top). Can I modify somehow the schematic to use my 2 wire probe or can I attach third wire [link2 in comments] (I understand disadvantages of this setup)?

Comment: [link2]: http://www2.schneider-electric.com/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/239000/FA239836/ru_RU/5pt100sensoren_e.pdf

Comment: At 5m the error will be insignificant as long as you use reasonable wire to connect.

Comment: If you do decide that you need more than 2 wire, why not go for 4 wire as this will give you added noise immunity too. As you are making the amplifier circuit it is as easy to use 4 wire as 3.

Comment: So I can use only 2 wires and extend them to 5m then connect single current source and measure voltage drop next to it?

Comment: Yes, if the wire was 1 square mm, then you have about 0.2 ohms so not very significant. But you can easily use a 4 wire connection if you wish.

Comment: what is your measurement accuracy? is the cable length is considerable for that?

Comment: You can use 2 wire and you make a jumper connection on the board input terminal. In this way you don't have a wire resistance compensation. The second option is to use 3 wires, yo will have a comensation for wire resistance, useful if you have long wires. Important thing is, that the cross section of wireshve to be the same, ie. using a shielded cable with 3 wires.

Comment: @user1582568
Can you give me an example of opamp circuit for 4 wires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can add the extra wire. Just bring it out to the element.

It should be noted that this is *not* a proper 3-wire RTD scheme and the extra wire only halves the error. A proper 3-wire scheme will reduce the error (in theory) to zero, or at least to the mismatch in resistance between wires.

Here is an example of such a scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0t3OP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To see how this works, consider *equal* resistances RL in each line. The voltage drop from ground to the lower end of R1 is \$(Ix-2\cdot I_X) \cdot R_L\$. The voltage drop from the top of the element to Vsense is \$+I_X \cdot R_L\$. The voltage drop across the element is just \$I_X R1\$.

So the voltage at Vsense relative to ground is:

\$-I_X \cdot R_L +I_X \cdot R_L + I_X R1 = I_X R1 \$

And the line resistances (if matched) don't have any effect on the measurement.

Comment: Shouldn't the low side sensing be connected to the (differential) sense input instead of the reference? Or at least I2 should be referenced somewhere below reference, to make easier building it. I do not understand the pros of this circuit with respect to a 'standard' four wire setup, what am I missing here?

Comment: @VladimirCravero It's a schematic representation - a real implementation would have a positive supply for the current source and a negative supply for the sink. The advantages over the Kelvin connection are twofold- first, it requires one less wire - that can be significant. Second it requires only a single ended amplifier rather than a differential amplifier. It also works well enough for most purposes.That's why the 3 wire setup is universal in industrial setups. In theory it's inferior, and in some cases that may even matter, so lab types tend to prefer 4-wire.

Comment: Took me awhile to understand how this may work. I think the bottom current source should be 2 times Ix.

Comment: @rioraxe absolutely right, fixed. Thought I did that the first time - thanks.

Comment: Now when Im looking on the bottom schematic of link1 (http://www.splok.org/PT1000_Interface) Im not sure anymore if it is setup with 2 or 3 wires :/
There is only one connection between IC2 and IC3 so it is 2 wire connection?
I will be grateful if someone could resolve this doubt.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Im stuck why in 3-wire all resistors must be equal https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439615/how-are-and-what-are-the-sources-coupled-to-a-3-wire-rtd-leads hope uo might have comment or answer

Comment: They’re similar wires of similar lengths,  so one would expect them to be closely matched. The matching is what allows the (variable with temperature) error to be mostly cancelled out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everybody misunderstood whtat Im asking ; Im not asking that. Let me make it more clear. Im asking does R3 (in the very bottom of my question after the edit) have to be equal to R2. I can understand why R1 and R2 are equal. But Im asking does the value of R3 matter. Hence does the value of sensing wire’s resistance matter?

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is called a kelvin connection, it eliminates the resistance of the wire by using a high impedance measuring circuit that is separate from the power cables http://slideplayer.com/slide/3603346/ slide 6

Run (three or four) wires out to the sensor as close as you can get it. Two for power (VCC and ground) and run two back to the Input.

Comment: laptop2d I just came across this question. could you also comment or answer on my question. im stuck at a point where answers didn't help an the question closed. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439615/how-are-and-what-are-the-sources-coupled-to-a-3-wire-rtd-leads

Comment: I can't answer it, it is closed. I also don't understand what you mean by current and voltage sources. Edit your question and make it more clear

Comment: Everybody misunderstood whtat Im asking. Let me make it more clear. Im asking does R3 (in the very bottom of my question after the edit) have to be equal to R2. I can understand why R1 and R2 are equal. But Im asking does the value of R3 matter. Hence does the value of sensing wire’s resistance matter?